# Does the calling AppDomain load the assembly in this scenario?

Tags: c#, .net

Let's say we have the following code:

```
static void Main(string[] args) 
{
    String assemblyIdentity = "SomeLibrary, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=01234567890abcde"; 
   
    AppDomain secondAppDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("second AppDomain", null, null);
    Assembly asm = secondAppDomain.Load(assemblyIdentity); 
}
```

I create a `secondAppDomain`, and want to load the assembly into this new AppDomain.

When `secondAppDomain.Load(assemblyIdentity);` is called, it is for sure that `secondAppDomain` will load the assembly and return a Assembly reference to the calling AppDomain (default AppDomain).

Now the calling AppDomain holds an assembly reference `asm`, my question is: does it mean calling AppDomain will also load this assembly automatically?

If calling AppDomain does load this assembly, it is a little weird because I didn't explicitly ask the calling AppDomain to load this assembly.

If calling AppDomain doesn't load this assembly, it is also weird since how can an AppDomain hold an assembly reference if it doesn't load this assembly?

Comment: Are you sure you want to be developing new software using [AppDomains](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/net-framework-tech-unavailable#application-domains) in 2021?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever no but a book I'm reading is based on AppDomain as foundation, so it is better for me to learn it even though it is outdate

Comment: @slowjams maybe switching to a more modern book is a better option.

Comment: @Franz Gleichmann there is no modern book that can hold a candle to Jeffrey Richter's CLR via C#

Comment: Have look at the remarks section of `AppDomain.Load` at the msdn. `If the current AppDomain object represents application domain A, and the Load method is called from application domain B, the assembly is loaded into both application domains.`

Comment: @thehennyy  could you also have a look at this question please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67177542/versioning-policy-with-assembly-load-and-assembly-reflectiononlyload